# FusedLocationAPI Noisy Data cancellation

Tags: android, noise, kalman-filter, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

Need your valuable suggestion for removing noisy locations provided by FusedLocation API using Kalman Filter as per some [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257812/android-gps-data-obtaining-and-filtering-how-it-improve-location-info/5325088#5325088) [some other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data/17114657#17114657) which says that GPS itself filter new location with Kalman filter. but there are also some other [articles](https://blog.maddevs.io/reduce-gps-data-error-on-android-with-kalman-filter-and-accelerometer-43594faed19c) which say we can smooth location using this exact filter. the question is???

so should I opt Kalman Filter or there is another way to tackle the noisy location point?

**my requirement is**

> - get the most accurate possible location
> - location can be fetched while in offline or low network area(as
>     FusedLocation API use network provider also)
> - there are some intentional off-road transit also possible by the user so
>     I can't discard off-road location (ex: by using SnapToRoad)